# Learning Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

If I needed to perform in Adobe Illustrator with only 20% of the ideal training time, what would you have me focus on?
Especially on logo design aspect

Comment: I see somebody down voted and close voted this answer. I'll try to give you an idea why. First you do not indicate what your proficiency level is. What do you already kown. What is 20% of ideal training time? You are aware that time with a trainer and training depends much on how focused and how self learning you are. There are no real shortcut to skill, just some students are more prepared. Writing a question that shows your level of preparedness is one indicator here...  Edit your question!

Comment: thanks for advice, and time to reply. First time posting here, so yeah i guess i had to be more specific next time. I  believe there is shortcut to skill - its basically How you initiate the skill, development process will largely determine how well and how fast you advance with that skill, when you start learning a task every minute counts you don't want to be wasting your time or effort on low return activities, you need to start the process by gathering an inventory of components and sub-skills that you'll need to know to master the skill

Comment: Well i can teach a person tu use illustrator in just about an hour. But i can nt teach them to design in a hour.

Comment: my question was not related with learning how to design, i was basically trying to find someone who already went through those steps and could list me some more important priorities that i could focus on Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: Learn the line tool, gridsnapping, smart guides and learn to snap to points. Those skills will enable you to 50% of everything you need to build. Then learn to use the rotate, scale and reflect tools.

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for, now i can say that you helped me i appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a logo in Adobe Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/86796/creating-a-logo-in-adobe-illustrator)

Comment: @ChrisJones you don't need to wait for the next time; [edit] your question and make it more specific this time!

Comment: @joojaa Please avoid answering questions in the comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pen tool
2. Pen Tool
3. Pen Tool
4. Pathfinder Operations / Shape Builder Tool
5. Alignment options
6. Path operations - Joining, cutting, altering
7. The Appearance Panel
8. Effects - Specifically the *Distort & Transform* effects (others can
   be learned much later)

While doing all this learn about snapping, outlining type, swatch management/types.

The truth of the matter is almost every single file I create uses a different set of tools/features. The items above are most commonly used. In fact, probably used in every single file I ever create to some degree.

Pen Tool is *intentionally* repeated because a very strong understanding of the Pen tool will translate to *many* other areas and tools. The Pen Tool offers a core understanding of how bezier curves are created and altered.

I would also *suggest* that you *disable* the `Bounding Box` (View > Hide Bounding Box). Without the Bounding Box you will be *forced* to learn better, often more accurate, ways to manipulate objects. You really don't *need* the Bounding box 99.9% of the time. It was added in CS4 to make Corel Users feel more comfortable. The **only** thing the Bounding Box does no other feature does is, easily resize an area text box without distorting text, that's it. If you need to scale or stretch.... use the Free Transform Tool. It does everything the Bounding Box will do (except the area text box thing) plus *more* and doesn't constantly get in the way of the visual preview of objects.

Comment: Thank you for not ignoring and taking the time to answer my question. It really means alot to me. This piece of information really saved my time. Thank you alot again, i appreciate it.